# Python, IDPropertyGroup, isinstance

Tags: python, scripting

In an exporter script i also want to export "custom properties".
In my script i have the active object:

```
x = bpy.context.active_object
```

I can access the custom properties by their keys:

```
k = x.keys()
```

Blender / Cycles seems to reserve some own properties in here with the keys:

- cycles
- _RNA_UI

The values of these seem to be of type IDPropertyGroup, investigation in the python console gives:

```
>>> type(x['cycles'])
<class 'IDPropertyGroup'>
```

In my script i want to handle this as a special case and for values of IDPropertyGroup rather use value.to_dict().

So in my script i have:

```
for k in x.keys():
    val = x[k]
    print("k %s type %s" % (k, type(val)))
    if isinstance(val, bpy.types.IDPropertyGroup):
        val = val.to_dict()
```

But this gives an error that i don't understand:
    line 194, in execute:
    if isinstance(val, bpy.types.IDPropertyGroup):

```
AttributeError: 'RNA_Types' object has no attribute 'IDPropertyGroup'
```

Googling for IDPropertyGroup i get this relationship:
    class bpy.types.IDPropertyGroup(bpy_struct)

I wonder where this error comes from, i would expect this to work.

Thanks for any hints,
Torsten

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such thing as *bpy.types.IDPropertyGroup* in *bpy.types*, hence this line:

```
if isinstance(val, bpy.types.IDPropertyGroup):
    ...
```

fails. Try `from bpy.types import IDPropertyGroup` you will get an *ImportError*.

```
>>> from bpy.types import IDPropertyGroup
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'IDPropertyGroup'
```

This is why that *isinstance* fails. I agree this is a little bit weird, but this changes the question a little.

> Why isn't it there and how would I use `isinstance` to test complexity of an ID property. Are there alternatives?

Because ID properties are a limited collection of types, it's perhaps no less crazy to check for `int, float, str, list`.

```
import bpy

x = bpy.context.active_object

for k in x.keys():
    val = x[k]

    if isinstance(val, (int, float, str, list)):
        print('simple', val)
    else:
        print('complex', val.to_dict())
```

You could also check if the ID property has an attribute `to_dict` instead, else it's a basic type.

```
import bpy

x = bpy.context.active_object

for k in x.keys():
    val = x[k]
    if hasattr(val, 'to_dict'):
        val = val.to_dict()
    print(k, val)
```

Even use the (always present) class type returned by `type(x['cycles'])`

```
import bpy

x = bpy.context.active_object
IDPropertyGroup = type(x['cycles'])  # <--- use this type's return in isinstance

for k in x.keys():
    val = x[k]
    print("k %s type %s" % (k, type(val)))
    if isinstance(val, IDPropertyGroup):
        val = val.to_dict()

    print(k, val)
```

Comment: Thanks for your hints.  The last example (isinstance with IDPropertyGroup) is what i tried (see my code above) and which gave an error.  This part does not seem to work and i don't understand why (i also tried writing just IDPropertyGroup).

Comment: it's not the same. read my third example again.

Comment: You're right, thanks.  I did not yet try it but it should work.